# GWT Development mode

Tags: gwt, gwt-dev-mode

I have started creating my first project with GWT. In first lines of code, it worked normally and I had no need to GWT Compile every time to see a simple change in my browser.

For client changes, a save file was enough and for server a save and refresh server. But now it has stopped working like before.

For the smallest change like adding a "Window.alert("msg")" I need to reGWTCompile the whole project to see it! What could have issued this?

Comment: Are you sure you're running in DevMode? (i.e. have `?gwt.codesvr=` in your URL)

Comment: Commit it as your answer! Yeap, that was the problem!

Comment: …better delete the question IMO, but there you go.

Comment: I am not sure that I am the only one who has faced this silly problem.

Comment: I was sure that had been asked several times already on SO, but then couldn't find any of them…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're running in DevMode (i.e. have ?gwt.codesvr= in your URL)